# how to check a value from select, if you choose to give a value then it is not necessary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html,
I have two select if one select contains a value, then the required attribute is deleted,and the third select must be required

```
<select class="form-control costume-{{$stud}}" name="subject-{{$stud}}[]" id="sub1" disabled="disabled">
   <option value="" selected> --------Select-------- </option>
   <option value="math,indonesia">Math (Indonesia)</option>
   <option value="math,english">Math (English)</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control costume-{{$stud}}" name="subject-{{$stud}}[]" id="sub2" disabled="disabled">
    <option value="" selected> --------Select-------- </option>
    <option value="science,indonesia">Science (Indonesia)</option>
    <option value="science,english">Science (English)</option>
</select>



<select class="form-control select-long costume-{{$stud}}" name="location_id[{{$stud}}]" disabled="disabled">
<option value="" selected> -----Select------</option>
   @foreach ($venue as $row)
       <option value="{{$row['location_id']}}">{{$row['location_name']}}</option>
   @endforeach
</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="enableSelect-{{$stud}}" onclick="getCheck({{$stud}});">
```

and this is my jquery

```
 function getCheck(id){

        var e = document.getElementById("sub1");
        var sub1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        console.log(sub1);

        if($('#enableSelect-' +id).is(':checked')) { 
            $('.costume-' +id).prop("disabled", false);
            $('.costume-' +id).prop("required", true);
            $('.visibility').show();
        }else{
            $('.costume-' +id).prop("disabled", true);
            $('.costume-' +id).prop("required", false);
            $('.visibility').hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think required attribute nor supported for select please refer the link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input

Answer (score 0):

Your JS doesn't correspond to the HTML, the selectors don't match up.

I would check form values and set the required like this :-

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if($(this).val() != ""){
    $('select').prop('required',false);
  }
});
```

This would work with your HTML as by default the select value is ""

You would also need required="true" on the  and your default option should be something like this -

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
```

on the select elements by default.

Comment: thank you, I have tried your solution but the third select must be required, so in essence I have three select, first and second select that one must be filled in with value and the third select must always be filled in value